# Why am I stuck in a loop even if I fulfilled the condition already?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Even though I already inputted scores from -100 to 100 only, I'm still stuck. Why is this like this? Please help me fix it!

```
players = int(input("Enter number of players: ")) 

while (players < 2 or players > 10): #Limits number of players to 2-10 only
    players = int(input("Error. Players should be 2-10 only. Enter number of players: "))

scores = input("Enter scores separated by space: ") 
data = list(map(int, scores.split())) 
record = data[slice(players)] 

for x in record:
    while( x < -100 or x > 100): 
        scores = input("Error. Scores should be -100 to 100 only. Please enter scores again separated by space: ") 
        data = list(map(int, scores.split())) 
        record = data[slice(players)] 

record.sort(reverse= True) 


values = [] 

for x in record:
    if x not in values: 
        values.append( x )
        if len(values) == 3: 
            break

print ("The runner-up score is:",values[1])
```

This is what happens:

```
Enter number of players: 3
Enter scores separated by space: 10000 2 3
Error. Scores should be -100 to 100 only. Please enter scores again separated by space: 233 4 5
Error. Scores should be -100 to 100 only. Please enter scores again separated by space: 1 2 3
Error. Scores should be -100 to 100 only. Please enter scores again separated by space:
```

As you can see, the third time I already inputted 1 2 3, but it still says error.

Please help me :( Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You never update `x`...

Comment: Where is `players` defined?

Comment: @Mureinik wait I thought X means an item in record..? So when I update the record, it also updates X?

Comment: @Rose unless you assign something to it, it won't update automatically

Comment: @DirtyBit Sorry, I didn't include my entire code. I'll edit it now.

Comment: x is not being updated in the inner while loop

Comment: What’s in the record?

Comment: @Rose why did you apply while instead of if? I couldn’t find the reason to use while there. As you haven’t updated  the values

Comment: Uhh I thought when I asked the user for another input for scores that means I'm updating the values..? And I used while because I want it to continue to check until it fulfills the condition.

Comment: @foo How do I do that? :(

Comment: replace the `while` with `if` and test it out.

Comment: @foo I tried but it only checks once :(

Comment: can you share the sample input and output case that fails for you ?

Comment: @foo Done! I edited it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part:

```
for x in record:
    while( x < -100 or x > 100): 
        scores = input("Error. Scores should be -100 to 100 only. Please enter scores again separated by space: ") 
        data = list(map(int, scores.split())) 
        record = data[slice(players)]
```

To:

```
while any( x < -100 or x > 100 for x in record):
        scores = input("Error. Scores should be -100 to 100 only. Please enter scores again separated by space: ") 
        data = list(map(int, scores.split())) 
        record = data[slice(players)]
```

The reason your code didn't work is because of this:

```
for x in record:
    while( x < -100 or x > 100):
```

You are looping with that specific `x`. When `record` is updated, that specific `x` will remain the same, and so, the `while` loop will never break.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! But what do you mean record and data are the same? What I'm trying to achieve in record is to limit the number of inputs in data to equal the number of players. That's why I thought the best option is slice.

Comment: Oh, i see! -----

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to write the code with your purpose:

```
players = int(input("Enter number of players: ")) 

while (players < 2 or players > 10):
    players = int(input("Error. Players should be 2-10 only. Enter number of players: "))
    continue
```

now it will endlessly ask you until the number of players is 2 - 10.

And change the below code like:

```
while any(x < -100 or x > 100 for x in record):
    scores = input("Error. Scores should be -100 to 100 only. Please enter scores again separated by space: ") 
    data = list(map(int, scores.split())) 
    record = data[slice(players)]
```

now should work

Comment: I tried to change it to if but it only checks once. So the next time I input values more than 100 or less than -100, it's now okay.

Comment: Basically, I want to restrict the scores inputted to -100 to 100 only.

Comment: Actually that one works already, the one I'm having a problem with is the second loop condition. The one with x < -100 and x>100. I'm sorry for not being clear!